# ImportError: No module named spherical_jn

Tags: python

I need to use the spherical Bessel function in my code and I saw there is the scipy.special module that has lots of special functions already defined, including the spherical Bessel functions. 
I want to use the pre-defined functions and I wrote the following two line of code:

```
import scipy.special
import scipy.special.spherical_jn
```

but I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.special.spherical_jn
ImportError: No module named spherical_jn
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38819303/435093 — you're probably using a very old scipy version.

Comment: Thank you. I checked and actually I am using scipy 0.18.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spherical_jn](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.1/scipy/special/_spherical_bessel.py#L7-L56) is a function, not a module, so you `import scipy.special` and then call the function on the module.

```
scipy.special.spherical_jn(...)
```